# is there a way to see only the Message Queuing section of Computer Management?

Tags: msmq, windows, shortcut, message-queuing, keyboard-shortcuts

frequently because I'm debugging Windows services that use MSMQ,
i need to review the Private Queues ...

I open Computer Management,
expand Services and Applications,
then expand Message Queuing and
Private Queues ... I know it's
only a couple of extra clicks
by it gets tiring because I
really do need to do it quite
often ...

some components can open outside of
Computer Management, e.g.:  Event Viewer
via Start, Run, eventvwr.

is it possible to do the same for
Message Queuing?

thnx ~~ gerry (lowry)

Comment: No. Why don't you write an app to expose the information you require?

Comment: @ john breakwell ... actually, I intend to do just that ... however, my spouse, Susan, just posted her first novel, "Ping", as an e-book at Amazon Kindle ... for that reason, my top priority project is to use the open source Orchard http://orchardproject.net/ to create a blog for Susan.  John, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow mark's advice and save a new .msc with Computer Management in it. Then open that MSC, expand Private Message queue or whatever section you work in regularly in the left treeview and when you exit, it'll ask whether you want to save the .msc - say yes and next time you open it, it'll open to where you were when you saved it.

Comment: this works, but it buries it deeply:  C:\Users\gerryLowry\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools -- so I've moved msmqPrivateQueues.msc to a more manageable path; I can run it from a command line AND I've set up a MagicWord for it in Eric Lawrences' awesome free SlickRun [http://www.fiddlertool.com/SlickRun/; http://www.bayden.com/]; I've marked @dirk's answer (because so afaik lets me mark just one), however the correct answer is really @mark + @dirk.  Thank you both; I'm thrilled.

Answer (score 3):

If you fire up mmc, and then File->Add Snap-In, you should see all the snap-ins there including MSMQ (Message Queueing, at least).  Then you can save the resulting console file and launch it.  (I don't have something with MSMQ available to check if it's there).

Comment: i do not see anything there although I see other useful items like Disk Management ... sadly, it appears only the name is given, e.g.: Event Viewer but not eventvwr. c:\windows\system32 does not seem to have anything useful; ditto c:\windows\msmq. it's looking like i'm out of luck unless there's a third party snap-in available. thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Yeah, this is distinct from the `.msc`s themselves (which are effectively just pre-made versions of this process).  In fact, some snap-ins are not exposed by any default `.mscs`: a notable and notorious example is "Certificates"; adding a certificate to the right store in some cases requires going through this laborious process just to access the Certificates snap-in.